Add Windows Boot Manager to GRUB on live USB
The focus of the question is not How to add Windows boot entry to GRUB or Ubuntu boot entry to Windows Boot Manager, but the "on live USB" part.
OS Prober is no longer ran by default as of nowadays grub. So I

added GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false to /etc/default/grub as per here.
and redo grub-install as per the answer given at Cannot update grub with parameters on live USB

However, I don't see grub-install giving output of adding Windows Boot Manager, and I don't see any /boot/grub/grub.cfg file get generated.
Running both update-grub and grub-mkconfig will give the error:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.

Fixing boot problems with live CD/USB is a common practice, but this error blocks me from doing it.
What's the fix please?

/cow is the live installer, and not normally updatable. How did you make USB flash drive? If you make a FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags and extract ISO into that partition, you can boot in UEFI mode (only). Then you could manually add a boot stanza to grub. But why. To boot live installer you have to go into UEFI boot menu where you also have the Windows entry. Or I prefer to create full install and now use SSD as much faster than flash drives. https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media
